# Twitter Search API to EXCLUDE Tweets with a Filter

Tags: search, twitter

I noticed there's an API filter to include only tweets with links.  Is there a way to do the opposite and return only Tweets with no links in them?

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `-filter:links` to your request:

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=foo+-filter:links
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=foo+-filter:links
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=foo+-filter:links